# AWK - How to filter using a command line argument ($1)

Tags: bash, awk, ksh

I have a script with the following line:

```
RHEL7.5> cat myScript.sh
...
awk -F":" '/^(EASYDOC)+/ {print $2}' /etc/oratab
...
RHEL7.5>
```

What I'm looking for is to replace the word "EASYDOC" with a command line argument ($1) in order to execute as "myScript.sh EASYDOC" and lettin EASYDOC replaces the pattern variable reference at awk line.

For instance:

```
awk -F":" '/^(something lets recognize $1 as arg)+/ {print $2}' /etc/oratab
```

would be desirable.
Thanks in advance. Néstor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to pass a shell variable into your awk script, use `-v`:

```
awk -F":" -v arg="$1" ...
```

Second, you won't be able to use the regex `/.../` syntax for anything but a string constant, so instead use the `~` operator with `$0`:

```
awk -F":" -v arg="$1" '$0 ~ "^(something lets recognize " arg " as arg)+" { print $2 }'
```

E.g:

```
$ var=foo

$ cat file
something lets recognize foo as arg:shut the door:the color is red

$ awk -F":" -v arg=$var '$0 ~ "^(something lets recognize " arg " as arg)+" { print $2 }' file
shut the door
```

Comment: Hi Jas !!! Thanks for your quick response. It solved my problem (I tried with -v flag but using at same time regex slashes "/.../": never thought about use "$0 ~ xxx".
Thanks again.